# iOS hiding activity indicator for multiple webservice call

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, uiactivityindicatorview

I am making call to two web services simultaneously, i am showing activity indicator at that time. Since either of the service can end first. I am not sure how to hide the activity indicator. I am thinking to use flag. But i am not sure whether that is the better way.Please help me with some better approach.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use AFNetworking library, which takes care of NetworkActivityIndicator for you. You just need to set [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManger sharedManager] setEnabled:YES]; in your app delegate.

Otherwise, keeping a counter is a good way to  do it. When you start each web request, just increment the counter and decrement the counter in the success or failure block. In those blocks, after decrementing the counter, if the counter is equal to zero, then set isNetworkActivityIndcatorVisible property of [UIApplication sharedApplication] to NO.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to create a method in AppDelegate.m class

#pragma mark activity indicator view
-(void)showActivityViewer:(NSString* )msg
{
    if (activityView1 == nil)
    {
        [activityView1 release];

        activityView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 580)];
        activityView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        activityView1.alpha = 0.8;

        UILabel* lblLoading=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 260, 180, 60)];
        lblLoading.numberOfLines=0;
        lblLoading.text=msg;
        lblLoading.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lblLoading.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [lblLoading setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottom];
        lblLoading.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [activityView1 addSubview:lblLoading];
        [lblLoading release];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityWheel = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.window.bounds.size.width / 2 - 15, self.window.bounds.size.height / 2 - 30, 30, 30)];
        activityWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
        activityWheel.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
        [activityView1 addSubview:activityWheel];
        [activityWheel release];
    }

    [self.window addSubview: activityView1];

    [[[activityView1 subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setText:msg];
    [[[activityView1 subviews] objectAtIndex:1] startAnimating];
}
```

Every time whenever you need to show activity indicator in the whole use this...It automatically manages all the things

To hide the indicator call this method,same in the AppDelegate.m class

```
-(void)hideActivityViewer
{
    [[[activityView1 subviews] objectAtIndex:1] stopAnimating];
    [activityView1 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Add one line Before `[self.window addSubview: activityView1]`

```
activityView1.tag = 110;
```

(You can set any number other than 110 also)

And Write following code to remove:

```
for(UIView *viewActivityIndicator in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].subviews)
{
    if(viewActivityIndicator.tag == 110)
    {
        [viewActivityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

If there is no special requirement than use some library instead of managing self.

Some Good Example : 
1. [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)
2. [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)